# How can i get the value from .service in .controller

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I want to get the users' value in .controller from .service, how can I do this? Can anyone help?

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $pouchDB) {
    $pouchDB.setDatabase("infoDB");
    $pouchDB.allDocs();
}

app.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", function($rootScope, $q) {
  this.allDocs = function(docs){
    database.allDocs({
        include_docs: true
    })
    .then (function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
            var users = result.rows[i].doc;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of calling the `setDatabase` function in a `pounchDB` service:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, pouchDB) {
  var result = pouchDB.setDatabase("infoDB");
  console.log(result);  
});

app.service('pouchDB', function() {   
  this.setDatabase= function(db){
    return db + " was called.";
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your `allDocs` function you need to return a users array and not keep re-assigning it in the loop:

```
.then (function(result){
    var users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
        users.push(result.rows[i].doc);
    }
    return users;
});
```

In other words, you are missing the `setDatabase()` function; in your `allDocs()` function you need a `return users` array of results; and in your controller you need to receive the value: `$scope.result = $pouchDB.allDocs();`

Answer (score 1):

From services you need to return Promise object, which will resolve or reject later based on network response. you need to add resolve handler and reject handler to know the promise async response.

A simulated working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DNL1i6gNnxLBSeaucBw3?p=preview)

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $pouchDB) {
  $pouchDB.setDatabase("infoDB");
  //resolve handler and reject handler to thenable object
  $pouchDB.allDocs().then(function(result) {
    $scope.users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      $scope.users.push(result.rows[i].doc);
    }
  },
  function(err){console.log('error')}
  );
});

app.service("$pouchDB", ["$rootScope", "$q", function($rootScope, $q) {
  this.allDocs = function(docs) {
    return database.allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    }); //return promise
  }
}]);
```